# DNS Problems with .pt configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dns-hosting

I have a hosting service with aplus.net, however I had a need to register a .pt domain, but aplus doesnt have this service, so I contacted a .pt registar, called hostingbug.net, to do this.

So now I'm owner of a .pt domain, `click.pt`. I gave hostingbug the aplus nameservers needed for propagation.

And here began the problems. When hostingbug tried to configure, the following error was displayed:

```
<<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_4.2 <<>> @64.29.151.221 click.pt. NS +norecurse
 (1 server found)
 global options:  printcmd
 connection timed out no servers could be reached
```

And they told me that aplus.net needed to create a **new dns zone** for .pt domains.

So I contacted aplus.net, and they didnt understand this issue, and told me that everything was fine with their servers, and sent me back to hostingbug.

So I'm felling like a ping pong ball right now... How can I configure this "new dns zone" for .pt domains? Anyone have clue of how to do this so I can tell them? Or should I cancel aplus services?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If hostingbug.net is your registrar, can they simply change the domain nameservers to

ns1.aplus.net
ns2.aplus.net
ns3.aplus.net

The 64.29.151.221 address does not seem to be a DNS server so querying that with dig is timing out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. They have changed the nameservers, but they still got the error.
That address is correct, atleast is what you can get here: http://faq.aplus.net/dns/

Answer (score 0):

well, there are two issues.

In the .pt root zone file, they have to say something like

> click.pt. IN NS ns01.aplus.net.
>   click.pt. IN NS ns02.aplus.net.

You don't need to have zone files on ns01.aplus.net in order for "dig click.pt NS" to work, since NS for .pt reply for this.

IN naming business, there are two entities: registrar and registry. For .com, verisign is the registry, godaddy.com is a registrar. I don't see click.pt NS records in the registry from my box.

Just tell them that you aplus.net created zones and see what their response is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will talk to them by tomorrow and see their response.